# Vapour pressure and Raoult's Law

Tags: vapor-pressure

The following question from my textbook assignment reads

> A mixture contains $1$ mole volatile liquid $A$ ($P_\mathrm A^\circ = \pu{100 mmHg}$) and $3$ moles of volatile liquid $B$ ($P_\mathrm B^\circ = \pu{80 mmHg}$). If the solution behaves ideally, the total vapour pressure of the distillate is?

Using Raoult's Law:
\begin{align}
  P_\text{total} &= P_\mathrm A^\circ \times \chi_\mathrm A + P_\mathrm B^\circ \times \chi_\mathrm B\\
  P_\text{total} &= \pu{100 mmHg} \times 0.25 + \pu{80 mmHg} \times 0.75\\
  P_\text{total} &= \pu{85 mmHg}
\end{align}

But the answer is $\pu{85.88 mmHg}$.

I tried searching online for an explanatory solution but all of them seem to use the mole fraction of solute **in vapour phase** without any explanation. I figured it was due to the word distillate. Can someone explain why do we need to use mole fraction of the vapour phase and not of the solute in solution?

Comment: The distillate is the condensed form of the vapor.

Comment: @Safdar You mean take out all the vapours of the solution separately and then condense **them** into a solution?

Comment: Exactly.. Then attempt to use Dalton's law of partial pressures to find the mole fractions in distillate/

Comment: @Safdar hey doesn't that mean the (condensed) distillate will form its own vapours?

Comment: It would but they have asked for the distillate of the given mixture and not the distillate of the distillate ...

Comment: @Safdar Could you possibly post a half solution? I'm confused whether it is the pressure due to the vapours separated out alone in another beaker (if so then it would be on the base of the beaker, isn't it?) Or the pressure due to the distillate's condensed as well as vapour existence?

Comment: @Safdar what is causing the pressure and on what is the pressure being applied. These answers might help me understand, thanks!

Comment: There is no such external pressure that is being applied(this is irrelevant), they are asking you to find the vapour pressure of the mixture that you get after you condense the vapours formed into a new liquid. Due to this, you would have a new solution whose vapour pressure you are asked to find

Comment: @Safdar Is it right if I put it this way? The vapours of the initial solution were condensed and separated in another container. The condensed solution developed vapours over itself. The vapour pressure to be calculated is of these vapours, on whatever the condensed solution is left.

Comment: Exactly. That should solve it..

Comment: Also do not use the homework tag anymore, it is deprecated(should not be used).

Comment: here "distillate" is to be considered as the vapour (of the orignal liquid) which is then condensed so you will have to find the composition of the liquid in vapour phase then use the composition in vapour phase as liquid phase as it was distilled.

Answer (score 5):

> [image: vapour-phase diagram]

During the process of distillation, we condense the vapours (B) of the mixture (A) to give a mixture (C) that has the same mole fractions as that of the vapour (B) of mixture (A).

In order to solve this question there would be three steps.

- Firstly, finding the vapour pressure of the initial mixture.
- Second, we find the mole fraction of components in the vapour phase of this mixture.
- The third and final part would be to find the vapour pressure of the distillate leading to our answer.

However, finding the actual composition of the vapours here, would be the biggest challenge in this question.

#### Step $1$

In order to find the vapour pressure, we use Raoult's Law which mathematically states:

$$P_T = \sum{P^\circ_i\chi_i}$$

Since this is a two-component system, the total pressure would be expressed as a sum of two terms for each component A and B.

$$P_T = P^\circ_\mathrm a \chi_\mathrm a +P^\circ_\mathrm b \chi_b$$

Substituting the values given in the question, we get $P_T= \pu{85 mmHg}$

#### Step $2$

The next step is to find the composition in the vapour phase. For this, we use the  property that the partial pressure of a component in the vapour phase is equal to the contribution of the same component in the liquid phase. Mathematically, it is equivalent to stating:

$$P_Ty_\mathrm a= P^\circ_\mathrm a \chi_a$$

Here, $y_a$ is the mole fraction of component A in vapour phase. Solving for $y_\mathrm a$, we get that $y_\mathrm a = \frac{5}{17}$, which implies $y_\mathrm b = \frac{12}{17}$.

#### Step $3$

The final is exactly the same as the first step, wherein you use Raoult's law to find the final vapour pressure of the distillate (mole fraction of components equal to that mole fraction of vapour in initial mixture).

Solving for the vapour pressure, you get $P_T^{'} = \pu{85.88 mmHg}$, which is the answer provided.